# How to install a bidet while not adding extra stress to my toilet seat

Tags: toilet, adapter

Recently my home bought a bidet and installed it with no problem.

[image: Overview]

A few weeks later the seat cracked.

[image: Crack From Top]
[image: Crack From bottom]

I was able to determine that it was the added thickness at the back of the seat caused by the bidet adapter that caused a gap and hence add stress to the toilet seat. After repeated use the seat gave way and the crack formed.

Now I've bought a new seat and I don't want the same thing to happen.

[image: Connector]
[image: Thickness]
[image: Gap]

I've found 4 potential solutions and I would like to know which would be best to solve this problem.

1. I can file off part of the front "plastic rods"/"teeth"/"spacers" (one can be seen in the picture displaying the gap) of the toilet seat so that the back ones rest back on the toilet bowl.
2. I can fill in the gap with a material (hoping for a good suggestion) so that there is no longer a gap to add stress.
3. I can add material the same thickness as the bidet adapter to each of the spacers so that the seat is level with the toilet bowl again.
4. Modify the bidet adapter so that it no longer requires the pressure from the toilet seat bolts to prevent it from moving. Instead I would try to create c-clamps to use around the adapter and toilet. (I don't like this solution, but it would return the toilet seat back to its normal position.

What solution would you try if this was in your home? Is there another that I have missed?

Comment: opinion based questions are off topic here

Answer (score 1):

I decided to put this in as an answer so I can include a picture.

It would probably be easiest if you can take enough material off the front spacers to get the rear spacers to contact the bowl rim. But by looking at the pics I doubt that will work because the rear spacers are so close to the hinge which can't be lowered. I would try to find some self-adhesive acrylic pads at your local hardware store to place under the rear spacers. The hard part would be getting the exact thickness you want. However, if you can get close with it (on the shy side) you could take enough material off the front spacers to get it stable.

Below are 7/8" furniture glides with a self-adhesive backing that may work for you.

[image]